# Determining the number of decimals in a float number

Tags: bash, shell

I want to run a command (such as ls -lrt) 49 times and every time 20 milliseconds after the previous run. What I have written in my bash file is:

```
 for i in `seq 1 49`;
     do
     v=6.$((i*20)  
     sleep $v && ls -lrt
     done
```

But it apparently does not differentiate cases like where i equals to 4 with the one that i equals to 40 as both result in v=6.8. What I need is to wait 6.080 for i=4 and 6.800 for i=40.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `printf` to format the number:

```
printf -v v '6.%03d' $((i*20))
```

`-v v` specifies that the variable `$v` should hold the result.

Comment: `-v` is bash specific, you can do without that with `v=6.$(printf '%03d' $((i*20)))` if desired.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Yes, but calling an external process makes the sleep for milliseconds completely useless.

Comment: Fair point though I'm not sure I think that's a realistic goal for something like `ls -ltr` in many cases anyway.

Answer (score 1):

how about `v=$(echo "scale=2;6+$i*0.02"|bc)`

this will keep increasing if the result was greater than `7`,  although it won't happen till `49`. But personally I think it is better than string concatenation.